# I am sending ID to Controller with Vue js in NET 5, but result is null

Tags: .net, vue.js, post, axios

My Conroller

```
    [HttpPost]
    public IActionResult Remove(int ID)
    {
        return Json(new { });
    }
```

My View

```
    new Vue({
        el: '#app',
        methods: {
            delTedarikci(ID) {
                axios.post("/Tedarikci/Remove", ID)
            }
        },

    })
```

Result
[image]

Devtools Network
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Quick fix will be:

```
axios.post("/Tedarikci/Remove/" + ID)
```

Since your are doing `Post`, it would be good to make your controller accept an object:

```
public IActionResult Remove([FromBody] RemoveInput input)
```

and your script:

```
axios.post("/Tedarikci/Remove", { id: ID })
```